# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: BEFORE_TRANSACTION_COMPLETION

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, tomcat

Development configuration :

Spring boot
MySQL
Apache Server
Tomcat 9.x.x

It works well in my develop system. But made war file into server and below error occurs when apache tomcat starts.

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
```

Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: BEFORE_TRANSACTION_COMPLETION

20-Dec-2021 09:40:54.191 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start

Answer (score 0):

Incompatible versions of SpringORM and Hibernate, Upgrade your hibernate or downgrade your Spring version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).