# Spring boot startup: "Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory', NoSuchFieldError BEFORE_TRANSACTION_COMPLETION"

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, maven

Okay so I have this Spring Boot project that was working, but then I did.... something and now it won't work any more.  When I try to start it up, I get the error: **org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: BEFORE_TRANSACTION_COMPLETION**

By googling just "BEFORE_TRANSACTION_COMPLETION", I found [this answer elsewhere on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70416129/java-lang-nosuchfielderror-before-transaction-completion), but it is not helpful.  The only answer says "Incompatible versions of SpringORM and Hibernate, Upgrade your hibernate or downgrade your Spring version."  But I can't figure out how to DO that.

Here's the longer version of the error message:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: BEFORE_TRANSACTION_COMPLETION
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) [spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) [spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) [spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) [spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) [spring-boot-2.5.5.jar:2.5.5]
    at com.OURCOMPANY.scheduler.SchedulerApplication.main(SchedulerApplication.java:19) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: BEFORE_TRANSACTION_COMPLETION
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.spi.PhysicalConnectionHandlingMode.<clinit>(PhysicalConnectionHandlingMode.java:48) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.32.Final.jar:5.4.32.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.buildJpaPropertyMap(HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.java:160) ~[spring-orm-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.getJpaPropertyMap(HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.java:130) ~[spring-orm-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Here is my POM which shows a what I've tried.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.OURCOMPANY</groupId>
    <artifactId>scheduler</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>scheduler</name>
    <description>scheduler</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <repackage.classifier/>
        <spring-native.version>0.10.4</spring-native.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-quartz</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>-->
<!--            <scope>runtime</scope>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-client</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee</artifactId> <!--jboss-javaee.jar-->
            <version>4.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging-spi</artifactId> <!--jboss-logging-spi.jar-->
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-remoting</artifactId> <!-- jboss-remoting.jar-->
            <version>jboss-5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-security-spi</artifactId> <!--jboss-security-spi.jar -->
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-serialization</artifactId> <!--jboss-serialization.jar -->
            <version>jboss-5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-common-core</artifactId> <!--jboss-common-core.jar-->
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jbosssx-client</artifactId> <!--jbosssx-client.jar-->
            <version>4.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jnp-client</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>




    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <classifier>${repackage.classifier}</classifier>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny</builder>
                        <env>
                            <BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>true</BP_NATIVE_IMAGE>
                        </env>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
<!--            <plugin>-->
<!--                <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>-->
<!--                <artifactId>spring-aot-maven-plugin</artifactId>-->
<!--                <version>${spring-native.version}</version>-->
<!--                <executions>-->
<!--                    <execution>-->
<!--                        <id>test-generate</id>-->
<!--                        <goals>-->
<!--                            <goal>test-generate</goal>-->
<!--                        </goals>-->
<!--                    </execution>-->
<!--                    <execution>-->
<!--                        <id>generate</id>-->
<!--                        <goals>-->
<!--                            <goal>generate</goal>-->
<!--                        </goals>-->
<!--                    </execution>-->
<!--                </executions>-->
<!--            </plugin>-->
<!--            <plugin>-->
<!--                <groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>-->
<!--                <artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>-->
<!--                <version>${hibernate.version}</version>-->
<!--                <executions>-->
<!--                    <execution>-->
<!--                        <id>enhance</id>-->
<!--                        <goals>-->
<!--                            <goal>enhance</goal>-->
<!--                        </goals>-->
<!--                        <configuration>-->
<!--                            <failOnError>true</failOnError>-->
<!--                            <enableLazyInitialization>true</enableLazyInitialization>-->
<!--                            <enableDirtyTracking>true</enableDirtyTracking>-->
<!--                            <enableAssociationManagement>true</enableAssociationManagement>-->
<!--                            <enableExtendedEnhancement>false</enableExtendedEnhancement>-->
<!--                        </configuration>-->
<!--                    </execution>-->
<!--                </executions>-->
<!--            </plugin>-->
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/release</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

As you can see above, I commented out portions related to JDBC or JPA or Hibernate.  Through IntelliJ I did Maven > Reload Project after each change.  So what the heck is it holding on to?

This project doesn't even NEED database connections at all.  It's just a scheduler that connects to a different project.  I initially set up the project from some kind of new Spring Boot project wizard in IntelliJ and I think mistakenly included some database plugins or something.  But now I can't get the project to stop looking for database stuff.

I guess maybe this has something to do with classpath?  It's the first time I created a Spring Boot application from scratch.

Lastly, IntelliJ is bringing up this popup, recommending a plugin for a dependency, Hibernate Core, which I'm not aware that I even included.

[image: JPA Buddy Popup]

Answer (score 1):

Okay I figured it out.  I can't believe I missed this.

My project required some dependencies that weren't available in central Maven repositories, so I copied the JAR files over from one of our other projects, into the LIB folder of my Scheduler project.  My mistake was that I shotgunned it, and basically copied a whole bunch of JAR files I didn't need.  Most of these, I think, just took up space and didn't cause any real harm.  However, copying hibernate-core.jar DID cause this problem.  I got rid of that JAR file and the scheduler started to work.

I'm pretty sure I have some more unnecessary JAR files in there too, so I'm going to continue the cleanup.