# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' java maven springboot with sqlite DB

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, sqlite, maven

Hello I am learning how to create a webapp using java maven with springboot and a sqlite DB.

But for some reason, I can't get it to work. I get this error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: BEFORE_TRANSACTION_COMPLETION
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1155) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137) ~[spring-boot-test-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46) ~[spring-core-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1406) ~[spring-boot-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:545) ~[spring-boot-test-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137) ~[spring-boot-test-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108) ~[spring-boot-test-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:187) ~[spring-test-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:119) ~[spring-test-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:127) ~[spring-test-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:191) ~[spring-test-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:130) ~[spring-test-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:241) ~[spring-test-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138) ~[spring-test-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$10(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:382) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$11(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762) ~[na:na]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:376) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:289) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:288) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:278) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364) ~[na:na]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:277) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:104) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.9.3.jar:5.9.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.9.3.jar:1.9.3]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.LazyLauncher.execute(LazyLauncher.java:50) ~[surefire-junit-platform-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.execute(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:184) ~[surefire-junit-platform-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:148) ~[surefire-junit-platform-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:122) ~[surefire-junit-platform-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:385) ~[surefire-booter-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:162) ~[surefire-booter-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.run(ForkedBooter.java:507) ~[surefire-booter-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:495) ~[surefire-booter-3.0.0.jar:3.0.0]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: BEFORE_TRANSACTION_COMPLETION
        at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.spi.PhysicalConnectionHandlingMode.<clinit>(PhysicalConnectionHandlingMode.java:50) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.7.Final.jar:6.2.7.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.buildJpaPropertyMap(HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.java:162) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.getJpaPropertyMap(HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.java:132) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1817) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
        ... 94 common frames omitted
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mywebapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>server</name>
    <description>Server for my Web App</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.kemitix/sqlite-dialect -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.kemitix</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-dialect</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.34.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.javassist/javassist -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.29.2-GA</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And my application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlite:src/main/resources/database/database.db
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.sqlite.JDBC
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.sqlite.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

I haven't made any changes to the java code since I haven't even got the springboot to compile yet.
but here it is.

```
package com.mywebapp.server;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

If you have any inputs, I need help.

Thank you for your time :) Have a great day

For springboot project to compile.

Comment: *NoSuchFieldError* indicates incompatible libraries. In your case between hibernate and spring-orm

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70416129/java-lang-nosuchfielderror-before-transaction-completion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to get the latest version of Spring Boot running with net.kemitix:sqlite-dialect version 0.1.0. This library uses hibernate-core 3.6.8 from 2011 as compile dependency (see here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.kemitix/sqlite-dialect/0.1.0)

You could try the dependency described on Baeldung instead: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-sqlite